# Проверять список с espresso

Tags: android, espresso

Есть список в который добавляю имена из другого списка, но на данный момент список пустой. 
Пытаюсь с помощью espresso тестов определить что в списке не содержится конкретное имя:

```
ViewInteraction textView2 = onView(withId(R.id.persname))
            .check(matches(hasDescendant(withText("Петя"))));
    textView2.check(matches(not(isDisplayed())));
```

Выбивает ошибку:

> android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with id: com.vm.sai:id/persname

Пробовал также и таким способом:

```
ViewInteraction textView2 = onView(
            allOf(withId(R.id.persname), withText("Петя"),
                    not(isDisplayed())));
    textView2.check(matches(not(isDisplayed())));
```

И ошибка следующая:

> android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: (with id: com.vm.sai:id/persname and with text: is "Петя" and not is displayed on the screen to the user)

Но к примеру в списке из которого я добавляю данные имена, проверяя есть ли оно, показывает что есть:

```
ViewInteraction textView = onView(
            allOf(withId(R.id.persname), withText("Петя"),
                    isDisplayed()));
    textView.check(matches(withText("Петя")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Из второй ошибки понял что возможно дело в самом view. Я её не прячу ничего с ней не делаю, поэтому решил проверить существует ли она.

```
onView(withId(R.id.persname)).check(doesNotExist());
```

Что в принципе и решило мою проблему.